# What is the slowest-decreasing function $f(x)$ for which $\int_N^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges? Does one even exist?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

What is the slowest-decreasing function $f(x)$ for which $\int_N^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges ($N$ is some large number)? Does one even exist?

Maybe it's easier to talk about growth speed than decreasing speed so an alternative question could be what is the slowest-growing function $f(x)$ for which $\int_N^{\infty}\frac{1}{f(x)}dx$ converges.

I know that $\int_N^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx$ diverges (so $x$ is too slow), and that $\int_N^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^\alpha}dx$ converges for $\alpha>1$ (so $x^\alpha$ is fast enough). Playing around with wolfram alpha it seems like $\int_N^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\log x}dx$ still diverges, but $\int_N^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\log^{\alpha}x}dx$ converges for $\alpha>1$. So the slowest growing function I could find for which it still converged is $x\log^{\alpha}x$ for $\alpha>1$. I am interested are there any slower ones? Is there a single slowest growing function for which that integral still converges (obviously up to multiplication by a constant or things like that)?

Comment: How do you measure growth speed? Do you consider monotonic functions only?

Comment: Pick two different function names. If someone propose an $f(x),$ they’d have to be specific about “which $f$“ they are talking about.

Comment: $f(x)=x^{1+\epsilon}$ in the second case converges for any $\epsilon>0,$ but not when $\epsilon=0.$ So there is no single “slowest,” at least for most definitions of “slowest.”

Comment: sure there isnt a single slowest $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$, but any $g(x)$ of the form $x\log^{\alpha}{x}$ will still grow slower than any f. I'm more interested in those general forms and which one is the slowest growing while still making that integral converge.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no slowest. Take for example, $\left(x\log(x)\log^\alpha(\log x)\right)^{-1}$. In a similar manner, we can take $\alpha=1$ and insert another $\log$ term with one additional iteration. If the power of this new logarithm is greater than $1$, the integral converges while it diverges when the power is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 5):

This is based on the comment by Clayton. Define
$$
\log ^{[k]} (x) := \underbrace {\log \log  \ldots \log (x)}_{k\text{ times}}
$$
for $x \ge {}^k \mathrm{e}$ (see [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)). Pick your favourite $\varepsilon>0$ and positive integer $M$. Set
$$
f_M(x) = x\left( {\prod\nolimits_{k = 1}^{M - 1} {\log ^{[k]} (x)} } \right)(\log ^{[M]} (x))^{1 + \varepsilon } 
$$
for $x \ge {}^M\mathrm{e}$ and $1$ otherwise. Then $\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{{f_M(x)}}}$ converges (by Cauchy condensation test) and $f_{M+1}(x)$ grows slower than $f_M(x)$ for each $M$.

Comment: ....and, continuing, there is a function $g$ so that $\int_0^\infty dx/g(x)$ converges, but grows slower than all your functions $f_M$.

Comment: Yeah, building off of GEdgar's comment - is this the most "efficient" way to create slow-growing functions for which that integral still converges? could one have come up with a better way , that grows slower than any $f_M$ (or maybe if it depends on some costant of it's own (or several constants) then it grows slower than any $f_M$ for some choice of them)? maybe using functions other than log? if so, is there a single best "way" to create such functions (again, up to constants)?